# Javascript Textbox "Scrubber"

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have not found a good solution: I have a text box in which users need to be able to type *specific* info into. For example the command might be "9030 OUT FU [1234 TEST]". I need to "scrub" this text box to ensure that the data was typed in exactly this format (caps not necessary). However there are approximately 50 of these different types of commands.

I am fairly new to javascript, but with good direction can understand it. Is this possible with javascript? Once the data is entered into the text box, it will run a function to return some information, and the text box will be clear for the next command. No 2 commands can be entered at the same time. I just need to check the format is 100% accurate for each command. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
function scrub(text) {
    var commands = new Array{"someCommand","anotherCommand",...};
    for (var i = 0; i <= commands.length; i++) {
        if (text.value.toLowerCase().equals(commands[i])) {
            //command is valid; do something here
        } else {
           alert("Invalid command");
        }
    }
    text.value = ""; //clears the text box
}
</script>
```

For your `textarea` do this:

```
<textarea onblur="scrub(this);" ...></textarea>
```

Comment: I suppose I would make it much harder with more information, not knowing exactly what I needed to ask in the first place. There are 5 major sections to my "command". They are as follows: (designator --> command --> type --> location --> misc).  The designator is a character combination that is preset, meaning I have a list of all the possible combinations it could be, i.e. 9030, W17, JP18 etc.

Comment: The "command" is the 50 different commands it could be, i.e. OUT, CL, CN, UR, IH, etc. Those too I will have a set number of and know exactly what they could be. The "type" the same with about 150 different "codes". The "location" must be in the [ *** ] form, but where the *** are may be anything at all. The misc as well, could be anything typed at all. Only "designator", "command" and "type" are exact items.

Comment: So it seems that the onblur="scrub(this);" solution seems that it would fit the best, but I copied it directly as written into my HTML file and it doesn't do anything.

Comment: <html>
<head>

<title>TEST</title>

<script type="text/javascript">   
function scrub(text) {
    var commands = new Array{"someCommand","anotherCommand"};
    for (var i = 0; i <= commands.length; i++) {
        if (text.value.toLowerCase().equals(commands[i])) {
            alert("valid");
        } else {
           alert("Invalid command");
        }
    }
    text.value = ""; //clears the text box
}
</script>

<body>
    
<textarea onblur="scrub(this);"></textarea>
    
</body>
</html>

Comment: @user703402 Did you actually put `someCommand` or `anotherCommand` into the textarea and click off of the textarea?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a set of keywords? And can be they be combined only in a certain fashion?

Looks like couple of regex patterns will be able to do the trick.

e.g: to match "9030 OUT FU [1234 TEST]" regex would be: `/\d{4} OUT FU \[\d{4}\]/`.

OUT FU and can be substituted with `\w{3}` and `\w{2}` respectively (unless you do not want *any* word to be allowed).

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions.

html:

```
<input type="text" id="code" />
<input type="button" value="test" onclick="alert(checkCode())" />
```

javascript:

```
function checkCode(){
var code = document.getElementById('code').value;
return code.match(/\d+ \w+ \w+ \[\d+ \w+\]/)!=null ? true : false;
}
```

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ is very helpful with regular expressions.

When you say "exactly this format", you have to understand that we have no clue what you mean. There are an infinite number of patterns that could be used to describe your example. The regular expression above will match if the code has a string of numbers, then a word, then another word, then an opening bracket, then a string of numbers, then a word, then a closing bracket.